# Retrieve files from remote HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My local machine does not have an hdfs installation. I want to retrieve files from a remote hdfs cluster. What's the best way to achieve this? Do I need to `get` the files from hdfs to one of the cluster machines fs and then use ssh to retrieve them? I want to be able to do this programmatically through say a bash script.

Comment: Try DistCp: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- Make sure there is connectivity between your host and the target cluster
- Configure your host as client, you need to install compatible hadoop binaries. Also your host needs to be running using same operating system.
- Make sure you have the same configuration files (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml)
- You can run `hadoop fs -get` command to get the files directly

Also there are alternatives

- If Webhdfs/httpFS is configured, you can actually download files using curl or even your browser. You can write bash scritps if Webhdfs is configured.

If your host cannot have Hadoop binaries installed to be client, then you can use following instructions.

- enable password less login from your host to the one of the node on the cluster
- run command `ssh <user>@<host> "hadoop fs -get <hdfs_path> <os_path>"`
- then scp command to copy files
- You can have the above 2 commands in one script

Comment: A follow-up question. How does [httpFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html) compare to the "client hadoop fs -get" solution in terms of performance?

Comment: httpFS and webhdfs are same. You can download using it, there is not need of hadoop binaries to do so.

Comment: what about in terms of performance? Is it faster to use the binaries instead of using httpFS? perhaps I should start another thread

Comment: "hadoop fs -get" will be faster than http.

Comment: You could also use HDFS NFS Gateway (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-storage/content/using_the_nfs_gateway_for_accessing_hdfs.html) and mount the HDFS to an NFS server and then connect that NFS server share to whereever you needed to. Note it would still have the same limitations as HDFS (eg. append-only writes), but you could at least programs access in a more conventional way.