# How to store Image file in Impala

Tags: database, image, hadoop, hdfs, impala

I have a Image file (jpg or jpeg) in local system and I would like to store in Impala Database, please assist me how could I do that?

Comment: Do you want to store the images in HDFS and keep references to it in the 'database'. Or do you need the actual content in the database? If it is the second and you cannot store it as binary data using Hive, you will have to find a way to store the content as a string with Impala. [Storing binary data (e.g. images) using Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257102/how-to-store-binary-data-in-hive), [Impala community on binary data](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Does-impala-support-binary-data-type/td-p/24366)

Comment: Either HDFS or Database would be fine but I would like to know how to retrieve the image.

Comment: I think you have three ways of going about this. 1. You find a way to transform your images to string to input in the database and use the same method to transform from string to image on retrieval. (serializer-deserializer) 2. You store images on HDFS, possibly with file paths stored in the database. To retrieve an image you would require a script fetching files from Hadoop similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305317/retrieve-files-from-remote-hdfs) 3. You use Hive and store the image as binary. Converting the binary back to an image will give you the result.

Comment: Thats fine, if you have any syntax for that please ping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a few ways of solving this depending on what is your exact requirement.

**1. Using Hive**

Hive allows you to store binary data in the Hive 'database'. Hive is similar to Impala although generally slower but with more functionality.
You can use the DataType `BINARY` in the table definition and load images using `LOAD DATA`.
Something like this might work (not tested).

```
Create table images (picture binary); 
LOAD DATA LOCAL inpath 'x/y/image.jpg' INTO TABLE images;
```

**2. Using Impala**

Impala [does not allow binary data](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Does-impala-support-binary-data-type/td-p/24366). What you can do is use a serialize-deserialize methodology. This means you convert your image to a String format that still contains all information necessary to transform it back. Once you need to retrieve an image on HDFS you will need to deserialize, meaning converting the string to the original format.

Using Python for example this would work like this:

```python
import base64

def img_to_string(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as imageFile:
        image_string= base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        print image_string

def string_to_img(image_string):
    with open("new_image.png", "wb") as imageFile:
        imageFile.write(str.decode('base64'))
```

**3. Using HDFS only**

Often storing the data in a database is not required. What you could do is just place the images in HDFS. If necessary you could keep the HDFS file path stored in a database. You can then retrieve the path using an Impala query. 
Getting a file from a remote location then requires you to run the following (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305317/retrieve-files-from-remote-hdfs)):

```
ssh <user>@<host> "hadoop fs -get <hdfs_path> <os_path>"
then scp command to copy files
```

Comment: Please let me know if any of these solve your problem and if so please accept the answer so others can benefit from my solution :)

Comment: I am very new here, please let me know how to accept the answer :)